# Firebase what is the proper way to return handle and reference in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am returning `DatabaseReference` and `Databasehandle` from my fetch function in order to detach the listener later. However, inside the closure in the `guard` statement I cannot return `(ref, handle)` since it's inside the handle definition. The strange thing is that Xcode does not yell at me and compiles fine if I simply put `return`. Is this correct?

I know I could have `DatabaseReference?` and `Databasehandle?` instead and return `(nil, nil)` in the guard statement. But it makes more sense to me that a reference and a handle should be returned no matter whether the fetch is successful.

```
func fetchQuestions(completion: @escaping (Question?)->()) -> (DatabaseReference, DatabaseHandle) 
{
    let ref = root.child("timeline").child(uid)
    let handle = ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        var question: Question?
        defer { completion(question) }

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Int] else { 
            return // Is this correct?
        } 
        ...       
    })
    return (ref, handle)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing your `fetchQuestions` *function* return value with the Firebase *closure* return value — the former is `(DatabaseReference, DatabaseHandle)` but the latter is just `Void` ;)

Your `guard` is actually returning from this closure
— I'm now using a *explicit* return type to be clear (i.e., `{ (snapshot) -> Void ...`):

```
func fetchQuestions(completion: @escaping (Question?)->()) -> (DatabaseReference, DatabaseHandle) 
{
    let ref = root.child("timeline").child(uid)
    let handle = ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        var question: Question?
        defer { completion(question) }

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Int] else { 
            return // Is this correct? Yes! (returning from Void closure)
        } 
        ...       
    })
    return (ref, handle)
}
```

This closure is passed as the last argument (i.e., `with:`) to the `observe` Firebase *asynchronous* function. This is a *very* common mistake ;)

Comment: Hi @Paulo, I realized it earlier already. But this makes it even clearer. Thank you!

Comment: @JGuo nice, glad to help ;)

Comment: @PauloMattos Why is it illegal to define this function like `func fetchQuestions(completion: @escaping (Question?)-> (DatabaseReference, DatabaseHandle) )`  ? Basically, return ref and handle instead of Void. Your answer does work though.